# Programming Languages that support XML literals

Tags: programming-languages, xml-literals

What are all the programming languages that support XML literals natively or via extension? I know of [VB.NET](http://www.ookii.org/post/xml_literals_in_visual_basic_9.aspx), [Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support), and [Factor](http://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2009/01/factor-supports-xml-literal-syntax.html). Any others?

Comment: It seems a little odd to count languages where somebody had to write an extension to the compiler in C++, but not count languages which were flexible enough that someone could write an extension to the language in itself.

Comment: @Ken: +1, good point. Added Factor to the list. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of a library that does it, but Common Lisp supports reader macros, which enables you to define your own syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl?  I've never used it, but [XML::Literal](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/XML-Literal/XML/Literal.html) looks like a way to do XML literals in Perl.

Answer (score 7):

[ECMAscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E4X).

Answer (score 5):

XSLT comes to mind. And yes, [it is a programming language](http://www.unidex.com/turing/utm.htm).

Answer (score 5):

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org) provides support for XML literals via [XML Boxes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Graphical_Syntax.html?q=xml#%28part._xml-boxes%29).  It also provides a very convenient S-expression based syntax for literal XML called [X-expressions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml).

Comment: This doesn't look like XML _literals_.

Comment: You can directly write XML, using XML syntax.  Here's a screenshot: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/samth/tmp/xmlbox.png

Answer (score 4):

Facebook published a [PHP Extension](http://github.com/facebook/xhp/wiki) that allows XML document fragments to be embedded in PHP code.

From the documentation page linked to above:

> XHP is a PHP extension which augments
>   the syntax of the language such that
>   XML document fragments become valid
>   PHP expressions. This allows you to
>   use PHP as a stricter templating
>   engine and offers much more
>   straightforward implementation of
>   reusable components.